# Do I have to pay taxes when bringing over R$10K into Brazil?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, brazil, brazilian-citizens

I know that when entering Brazil with over R$10K (or equivalent), these financial goods need to be declared on a [e-DPV](https://www.gov.br/receitafederal/pt-br/servicos/aduana/viajante/e-dbv). However, it is not clear whether the [Receita Federal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receita_Federal_do_Brasil) would tax me on this money.

For context, I am a Brazilian citizen, travelling back from the USA, where I earned the money and paid income tax on it.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a resource that clearly stated you should (or shouldn't) pay any taxes on it, but reading the *[instrução normativa](https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Legislacao/Ins/2010/in10592010.htm)* (art 6º, §4º) published by the Receita Federal about tax treatment applicable to traveller goods it seems that taxes should be paid only if you bring goods above the US$500 limit, but not cash.

It seems you must only [fill the e-DPV and present it to Receita Federal before passing through the x-ray scanners](https://www.edbv.receita.fazenda.gov.br/edbv-viajante/help/pt_BR/) so that the e-DPV has legal validity.

Comment: Another bit of context is that I have lived abroad for more than one year, which puts me in this special condition regarding the $500 goods limit: http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/aduaneira/viagens-internacionais/viajantes/viajantes-em-situacoes-especiais

Answer (score 1):

There are no tax to pay when you enter Brazil. If you have more than R$ 10.000,00 you will pay it in your Tax return (Imposto de Renda).

There are a verification of amount of your declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The previous [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/51570) from Afetter is right. I did enter Brazil with over R$10K and didn't pay any taxes. You have to fill the e-DPV and declare it to the customs officer of the *Receita* showing the printed form (after the passport checking by the *Policia Federal*). They will count the money.

If you don't declare the money and they find it, then it will be confiscated and you'll lose it!